# Auto-Referencia en MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Tengo una colección la cual tiene un campo padre que hace referencia a documentos de la misma colección, ahora lo que hago es llamarlos y buscar el `id` del padre y crearles un campo hijos en donde van todos los subdocumentos, esto lo hago en el controlador con un ordenamiento y no se cómo hacer que lo realice la Base de Datos, pienso que podría ser con un `mapReduce` pero no tengo muy claro como se realiza.

Mi colección es parecida a esta:

```
0:{
    id:1,
    nombre:'pepito perez'
},
1:{
    id:2,
    nombre:'jony se',
    padre:1 
},
2:{
    id:3,
    nombre:'rojas del totaso'
},
3:{
    id:4,
    nombre:'rosa melano'
    padre:3 
}
```

Lo que quiero lograr es lo siguiente:

```
0:{
    id:1,
    nombre:'pepito perez'
    hijos:[
    {
        id:2,
        nombre:'jony se',
        padre:1 
    }
    ]
},
1:{
    id:3,
    nombre:'rojas del totaso',
    hijjos:[
        {
            id:4,
            nombre:'rosa melano'
            padre:3 
        }
    ]
}
```

De antemano muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Estructura con referencia a los padres

[image: Model Tree Structure with Parent References]

El siguiente ejemplo almacena la referencia a la categoría padre en el campo `parent`:

```
db.categories.insert( { _id: "MongoDB", parent: "Databases" } )
db.categories.insert( { _id: "dbm", parent: "Databases" } )
db.categories.insert( { _id: "Databases", parent: "Programming" } )
db.categories.insert( { _id: "Languages", parent: "Programming" } )
db.categories.insert( { _id: "Programming", parent: "Books" } )
db.categories.insert( { _id: "Books", parent: null } )
```

- La consulta recupera los hijos inmediatos de un nodo es rápido y sencillo:

  `db.categories.findOne( { _id: "Databases" } ).children`
- Puedes crear un índice para el campo `children` para habiliar una búsqueda rápida por `child nodes`:

  `db.categories.createIndex( { children: 1 } )`
- Puedes consultar un nodo hijo para encontrar su nodo padre, así como sus hermanos:

  `db.categories.find( { children: "MongoDB" } )`

---

También puedes hacer lo contrario, te dejo información oficial de donde he obtenido la respuesta (inglés). Espero te sea de apoyo:

- [Model Tree Structures](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/applications/data-models-tree-structures/)
- [Model Tree Structures with Child References](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-child-references/)
- [Model Tree Structures with Parent References](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-parent-references/)